# What would "agenda" be in Ancient Greek?

Tags: translation-explanation, ancient-greek

How should *agenda* be translated into Greek?

The first thing that comes to my mind is just taking the future passive participle, neuter plural, of ἄγω (ᾰ̓χθησόμενα); however, there is a slight difference in meanings: in Latin, *ago* means "I act", "I do". In Ancient Greek, however, ἄγω means "I lead".

Thus, *agenda* literally means "the things that will be done", but *ᾰ̓χθησόμενα* means "the things that will be lead", which is not exactly the same.

So, what would be a semantically correct translation of *agenda* in Ancient Greek?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The closest Greek equivalent to a Latin gerundive is one of the verbal adjectives ending in -τέος (formed on the aorist passive stem). Both ποιέω and πράττω – unlike ἄγω, as you note – are generally equivalent in sense to Latin *ago* when it means 'to do.' Therefore, the corresponding equivalents to the neuter plural gerundive *agenda* would be τὰ ποιητέα and τὰ πρακτέα, respectively. Both of these, like *agenda*, mean 'the things that need to be done.'

Comment: FWIW, πρακτέα is the modern Gr translation equivalent of agenda.

Comment: A collection of πρακτέα (sing. πρακτέον), are the items (to-do or what was done) of a πρόγραμμα (see below).

Comment: @gts, Sure, πρόγραμμα is a word that can be translated as 'agenda' (though it has other meanings too). However, the original question seemed to me to be getting at the larger question of how Latin gerundives can be rendered in Greek; so I framed my answer accordingly, by pointing to the adjectives in -τέος.

Comment: Yes of course, this answer it's spot on when it comes to reasoning morphologically about it; and when translating this word and taking into account what context the latin use of agenda is in, I think πρόγραμμα is a pretty strong candidate too (regardless of both agenda and πρόγραμμα having other meanings too).

Answer (score 4):

*Πρόγραμμα* is probably as good a candidate as any can be, http://stephanus.tlg.uci.edu/lsj/#eid=89478 (LSJ at TLG).

Also, Brill Dictionary of Ancient Greek (2015) has a meaning for *Πρόγραμμα* of 'that which is written first, order of the day' as per Demosthenes' and Aristotle's corpora; and the Cambridge Greek Lexicon (2021) defines it at *programme of business, agenda* (for an official body).

[Update]

As a translation precedent http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0045%3Achapter%3D44%3Asection%3D2 (Greek text containing πρόγραμμα) and translation to English (but, specifying 'list of agenda' maintaining the latin meaning instead of 'the agenda') http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0046%3Achapter%3D44%3Asection%3D2

[Update 2]

As discussed in comments, and probably useful to have better visibility here as part of the answer, *agenda* is a Medieval Ecclesiastical Latin word, and as such it is being used in the context of Church/State (i.e. examples at https://logeion.uchicago.edu/agenda), and as such I believe that *Πρόγραμμα* presents a good case as a candidate translation word to ancient Greek when taking context into account (list of items to do for an official body).

Comment: But... isn't this too specific? Quite close to its English usage? Agenda refers to things that simply  have to be done, at some  point, *without* specification of modalities, no?

Comment: Not sure that it is simply used to refer in general to any things to be done; as this is a translation question then the context (interdependent with modality) has to be taken into account. If no context it'd be *things to be acted on* (πρακτέα), but when translating (more than equivalency of words is needed) agenda is a medieval Latin word and it is being used within a specific Church/State context (e.g. Latin usage examples at Logeion https://logeion.uchicago.edu/agenda) and as such it also came to have the secondary meaning of 'ritual'. So, as such to me πρόγραμμα looks like a good fit.

Comment: Having said that, it would be interesting if it could perhaps be found whether there are any Ecclesiastical Latin texts containing 'agenda' that are translations of Church Greek (Late Koine, Church Fathers etc), and check how the translation was done there. This would probably offer a definitive answer.